# Free self-hosted project management with time tracking

Tags: web-apps, project-management, time-management, wiki, self-hosted

It should be a free web application for self-hosting. Source code must be available.

Those would be the optimal features:

- Access from mobile devices should be easy
- Multiple projects support
- Multi user support
- Flexible issue tracking system
- Per project wiki
- Time tracking

  - Start/stop buttons to easily switch between tasks you are working on
- Quick select of the latest selected projects
- Button to switch to another project and switch back to the former one (for example: you are at customer A, suddenly customer B calls so you intermediately work for another project for half an hour)

At the moment I use [timeeffect](https://github.com/rubo77/timeeffect) which doesn't have all need features.

Comment: https://www.redmine.org/

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [YouTrack by JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/) While this may not do everything you require, at least it can offer:

- Self-Hosted Tomcat Installation
- Bug & Issue Tracking
- Project Management
- Time Management
- Free for 10 users
- Follows Agile methodologies (If so required)
- Web-Based with keyboard shortcuts for most major tasks

You can also generate reports that shows time worked on each task if this is also a requirement.

You could watch some [Webcasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAzV8xYF0nY&list=PLQ176FUIyIUZNcurItjJWEXpObjMtldh4) to see if the product is right for your exact needs. For a small team with many projects, it could fit into your workflows.

Comment: It seems like you don't get the source code

Answer (score 1):

I work on Twproject, a web-based Project management and issue tracking with a flexible time recording module (http://twproject.com).

There are several ways to record time:
1) using start/stop buttons
2) using a weekly view
3) using a daily view
4) every time you close/work-on an issue

Time records are aggregated into projects.

Every project has its own discussion, it is not a wiki, but it is really similar.
Supports multiple users and projects.

Is accessible via mobile.

You can install it on your server or use it on a dedicated instance on Amazon AWS.

It is free for Non-profit on their servers.

Comment: I don't find a free version there. Where do I get the source code?

Answer (score 0):

Would like to recommend you the Project Management software [Output Time](http://www.outputtime.com/on-premises-project-management/) which offers Self-Hosted version. Also it bundles Time Tracking, Expenses Management and Invoicing etc along with Project Management. The Self-Hosted version is available as two separate patches for Windows only and Wep-App respectively for our business convenience.

If you have a Windows PC but don't have access to a Web server, you can go with ‘Output Time for Windows’ patch.

And, if you have a Web Server, you can choose ‘Output Time Web App’ patch.

Output Time is Clear and Transparent that creates a visual project structure and helps you to Stay on Top & Get organized as it keeps all discussions, tasks, designs as well as documents in a centralized location. It is simple and features rich.

You can have a live demo of it at [Output Time Demo](http://demo2.outputtime.com/outputtime.com/application/index.php/signin)

Comment: Thanks, but this seems not to be  "a free web application for self-hosting" as questioned. or where do you find the self hosted version?

Comment: I only see a  30-day Free Trial version

Answer (score 0):

Time tracking provides necessary information on efficiency, productivity, and the number of resources consumed against the amount of time spent. Companies and individuals have come to realize the key to achieving their goals. This key is tied closely to how best they can manage one of the most limiting resources – time.

This realization is a fact, and the achievements of businesses and organizations that have the best applications that help them in managing time have proofed this. Wasted time is money lost, or in other words, time is money. Hence we have work hours tracker as our saviour.

CuteHR Features let users work for many tasks on a single dashboard.

Some Unique features of CuteHR are.
1. Work Hours Tracker
2. Project Management
3. Attendance and leave management.
4. Document management.
5. Request management.
6. Client Management.
7. Reports and Analytics.
8. And many more.

**[Thanks](https://www.cutehr.io/hours-tracker/)**.

Comment: This doesn't seem self hosted

Comment: Welcome to [softwarerecs.se]! Are you affiliated with this website? It reads more like an advertisement than a typical Stack Exchange post. Please read the [Help Center](/help/promotion) for more details.

Comment: I am not affiliated with this website. I have personally used this website for my office and I found it very helpful. That's why I shared my thoughts.

Answer (score -1):

Everhour is a very innovative online time tracker, and can integrate with several project-management and issue-management systems. It's typing-driven, not button-driven, but for a fast typist it is quicker.

Comment: [Everyhour](https://everhour.com/pricing/) is quite expensive and not self-hosted, I added this to my Question

Answer (score -1):

Check [Foswiki](http://foswiki.org). It is an enterprise grade wiki.

While it isn't have (AFAIK) an ready to run time tracking application, it is possible to create your own "wiki application" (using builin macros) so, maybe a sort of time-tracking too. As your project grows you can build more and more e.g. workflows and so.

Check it, or maybe you can ask developers @irc: http://foswiki.org/Community/InternetRelayChat

Comment: "Code  your own" is not a valid recommendation for software.

Comment: @IraBaxter you should check the software, what I recommending, before commenting. If someone recommend excel as a tool for "calculating expenses", it isn't valid because he need enter macros into the cell? It is the same, with the foswiki. So again, check first.

Comment: This is "software recommendations".  Have you used this to implement a time tracking application?  No? So you have no specific experience with this being a solution.   Hardly what I would call a good recommendation.

Comment: @IraBaxter Ok, it is YOUR opinion. I'm using foswiki for much more complicated tasks, like workflow with problem tracking and so.. Im surprised how you can critize something about your knowledge is zero. (I recommendiag a tool, what i'm using routinely). Solution is easy - go, and check it yourself. ;)